# writing a byte with the "write" system call in C

Tags: c, system-calls

Using the system call write, I am trying to write a number to a file. I want the file pointed by fileid to have 4 as '04'(expected outcome).

```
    unsigned int g =  4;

if (write(fileid, &g, (size_t) sizeof(int) ) == -1) 
{
     perror("Error"); exit(1);
}
```

I get the output '0000 0004' in my file. If I put one instead of sizeof(int) I get 00.

Is there a specific type that I missed ?

PS. I have to read this value form the file also, so if there isn't a type I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: You want the file to contain a single byte, whose numeric value is 4.  Is that correct?

Comment: You're writing an int, not a byte. Try a byte.

Comment: @EJP byte is not a valid C data type. Sorry if that's not what you meant.

Comment: So, err, try a char then. NB unless I am much mistaken, sizeof already is a size_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeof(int) will return 4; so actually, the code is writing four bytes.

Change the type of 'g' from

```
unsigned int
```

to

```
unsigned char
```

... and, change

```
sizeof(int)
```

to

```
sizeof(unsigned char) .. or sizeof(g)
```

Then you should see that only one byte '04' will be written.

Comment: `sizeof char` is per definitionem 1. No need for cluttering the source with it.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer `sizeof(*g)` doesn't even compile. `g` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

If writing 1 byte of `g` will print 00 or 04 will depend on the architecture. Usually, 32-bit integers will be stored in the memory using little-endian, meaning the less significant byte comes first, therefore 32-bits `int` 4 is stored as 04 00 00 00 and the first byte is 04.

But this is not always true. Some architectures will store using big-endian, so the byte order in memory is the same as its read in 32-bit hexadecimal 00 00 00 04.

[Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance I would recommend using `uint8_t`, which is defined in `<stdint.h>`.  On basically all systems you will ever encounter, this is a typedef for `unsigned char`, but using this name makes it clearer that the value in the variable is being treated as a number, not a character.

```
uint8_t g = 4;
if (write(fileid, &g, 1) != 1) {
    perror("write");
    exit(1);
}
```

(`sizeof(char) == 1` **by definition**, and therefore so is `sizeof(uint8_t)`.)

To understand why your original code did not behave as you expected, read up on [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save only one byte, it will be more appropriate to create a variable that is of size one byte and save it using `write`.

```
unsigned int g =  4;
unsinged char c = (unsigned char)g;

if (write(fileid, &c, 1 ) == -1) 
{
     perror("Error"); exit(1);
}
```

If you lose any data, it will be in the program and not in/out of files.